# How to render specific component when route change using React Router 4?

Tags: react-router

I have following route,

```
<Route exact path ='/' component={Posts} />
<Route exact path ='/:category' component={Posts} />
<Route exact path ='/new' component={NewPost} />
```

issue is when I go to `/new` route, `Post` component is getting rendered as well along with `NewPost` component. How to avoid that?.

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap route inside  Component. It worked.

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

<Switch>
  <Route exact path ='/' component={Posts} />
  <Route exact path ='/:category' component={Posts} />
  <Route exact path ='/new' component={NewPost} />
</Switch>
```